# How do I hit a target without a hit cross? (War Thunder aiming)

Tags: war-thunder

Is there a way to measure distance on a map on War Thunder? In realistic/sim battles, without an aiming reticle, I'm trying to find a way to aim and hit a far target with cross hairs by knowing the distance, but I don't know how to measure it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a **Telemeter**. But it's inaccurate, on distances over 600m it will show >600 and it's really slow.

If you want to try it yourself, you have to bind a key to it (go on keybindings, tank controls).

My suggestion is: play your tanks, get used to them, learn maps and common spots. 
The more you play, the better you will be at guessing the enemy distance.

Comment: There's a Gunner skill that improves rangefinding, and allows mostly accurate measuring up to 2k m when maxed out.